# How to pull specific string from url with regex?

Tags: node.js, regex

I have a url and I am trying to parse a string from it.

`https://www.example.com/files/filename1/whop-die-do/434ssdf/rewth`

The url will always be: `https://www.example.com/files`

The string I am trying to find is: `filename1/whop-die-do`

So other examples would look like this:

```
https://www.example.com/files/filename2/apples/asdfasdf/reasdfasdfth
   \---> filename2/apples
https://www.example.com/files/bloop/oranges_r_great/zcvr/asdfasd
   \---> bloop/oranges_r_great
https://www.example.com/files/name4/Wowzers123/as4t/532sadf
   \---> name4/Wowzers123
```

This is the current regex pattern I am using `/filename2\/([^/]+)/` (courtesy of @Wiktor)

This works only if the it contains `filename2` within the string. Is it possible to have it automatically match after the: `https://etcetc`

Comment: Looks like you are looking to create a regex, but do not know where to get started. Please check [Reference - What does this regex mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618) resource, it has plenty of hints. Also, refer to [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736) post for some basic regex info. Once you get some expression ready and still have issues with the solution, please edit the question with the latest details and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: This seems like a bit more of an advanced regex so its hard to get started. I know very basic regex but finding and returning is pretty new for me.

Comment: It is a basic regex. Negated character class, capturing group and anchors will do.

Comment: Ok ill looks those up for now

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So... I was able to get something like this: `\b(\w*files\/\w*\w)\b` and it is grabbing the word `files/filename1` but i cant figure out how to grab the next section...

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/c503Sh/1, the pattern is `/[^/]*files/([^/]+/[^/]+)`

Comment: Hmm... can you point me a direction to look at? I realized I dont need `files`, I need `filename1/whop-die-do`, `filename2/wowzers`. Is there some regex that says means: start from here.... Really appreciate the help.

Comment: I saw that I can ignore from the beginning: `^(?!.*https://www.bloop.com/files/).*$(/[^/]+[^/]+)` but I need some help with the syntax

Comment: I can do: `/[^/]*filename1/([^/]+)` but the `filename1` will change from time to time

Comment: Once you understand what requirements you have, please update the question. First, rules must be devised, then, you may think of the pattern. Besides, regex flavor/programming language must be specified, add a tag to the question.

Comment: Edited the question to be more concise.

Comment: You already know `[^/]+`, use it.

Comment: with: `\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]+)` it matches 3x